# Is it possible to call derived class functions from Base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual-functions

I need clarification in calling methodologies, i have a base class and from which i try to call derived class function using derived class object. is it possible

Pls tell me whats wrong in my code in this senario

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <malloc.h>

class derived;

class base
{
public:
    base()
    {

    }
    ~base()
    {
    }

    void setdptr(derived* dptr)
    {
        m_dptr = dptr;
        dptr->sayHello();
    }

    virtual void addfunc()
    {

        printf("base class add");
    }

    derived *m_dptr;

};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived()
    {
    }
    ~derived ()
    {
    }

    void addfunc()
    {
        printf("derived class add");
    }

    void sayHello()
    {
            printf("Say Hello");
    }

    void setDeriveToBase()
    {
       setdptr(this);
    }

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    derived dp;
    dp.setDeriveToBase();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to call derived class functions from Base class???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `setdptr` function in class `base`, you don't have the `derived` class fulle defined yet so the compiler doesn't yet know what members are in `derived`.

Move the actual *definition* of `setdptr` to after the declaration of `derived` and it should work.

Something like this:

```
class derived;

class base
{
    // ....

    void setdptr(derived* dptr);

    // ....
};

class derived : public base
{
    // ....
};

void base::setdptr(derived* dptr)
{
    m_dptr = dptr;
    dptr->sayHello();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that

```
void setdptr(derived* dptr)
{
    m_dptr = dptr;
    dptr->sayHello();
}
```

is illegal. You only provide a forward declaration to `derived`, so you can't use any methods from it, since the compiler knows nothing about the class, other than that it exists.

You'll need to separate declaration from implementation, move the implementation in a `cpp` file, and include the header which defines `derived` in that file.

**But calling derived methods from a base class is a code smell, you shouldn't need to do it**.